# Unable to add WS-Security header to request built from web reference

Tags: c#, ws-security, soapheader

I've consumed a WebReference and the receiving server requires a WS-Security header:

```
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="Example"> 
    <wsse:Username> ... </wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="..."> ... </wsse:Password>
    <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="..."> ... </wsse:Nonce>
    <wsu:Created> ... </wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
```

I'd assumed this would be included in the WSDL however after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726127/adding-soap-implicit-headers-to-wsdl) I understand that the logic should be separated.

The client class I use to perform the request contains a Proxy property `IWebProxy:HttpWebClientProtocol`. I believe this is where I should provide the header/override information. Please could someone confirm this?

I also have some code that I know generates the correct headers. However I'm unsure how to specify these headers/elements without modifying the `WebReference`.

```
public static Tuple<EndpointAddress, BindingElementCollection, string, string> PrepareGlowsAuth(string endpoint)
{
    EndpointAddress soapEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(string.Format("{0}/{1}", (IsProduction ? productionBaseUrl : testingBaseUrl), endpoint));
    BasicHttpsBinding binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
    binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;

    BindingElementCollection elements = binding.CreateBindingElements();
    elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>().EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;

    return new Tuple<EndpointAddress, BindingElementCollection, string, string>(soapEndpoint, elements, "username", "password");
}
```

Would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction!

Update: After following advice I cant see the Client or Response classes.

[image: Image to show the classes arent defined]

Comment: Have you seen this s/o post?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663007/invoking-a-web-service-with-ws-security-from-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you would go about injecting the credentials into the request without altering the client class is as follows:

```
// Assume that you named your "Connected Service" com.example.foo

foo.bar requestObj= new foo.bar();

// Fill in your request object
bar.FirstName = "Someone";
// etc.

// Set up the authentication using the function you provided
var glowsAuthData = PrepareGlowsAuth("expressRateBook");

// foo.<object name>Client is automatically created, this is the generated
//   proxy class for communicating with the intended web service
foo.barClient client = new foo.barClient(new CustomBinding(glowsAuthData.Item2)
                                         , glowsAuthData.Item1);
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = glowsAuthData.Item3;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = glowsAuthData.Item4;

// Use the client to send the request object and populate the response object
// foo.<object name>Response is automatically generated when VS generates 
//   the code for "Connected Service". It also makes it the return type 
//   for foo.barClient.barResponse(foo.bar);
foo.barResponse responseObj = client.barResponse(requestObj);
```

Assuming no exceptions, `responseObj` will contain the response from the server. No direct modification to the generated client created using the WSDL required.

Comment: Many thanks for this. Seems perfect. One issue though, I cant seem to find the WebServiceClass in System.Web.Services. Have ensured a ref to the dll v4

Comment: So I have `WebService requestObj = new System.Web.Services.WebService();`

But nothing for `WebServiceClassClient client = new WebServiceClassClient`.
 @Tarek, do I have to generate this class?

Comment: Unfortunate naming on my part, sorry. `requestObj`'s type should be the proxy class generated by VS when you import the WSDL. I named mine com.dhl.wsbexpress.expressRateBook. I was trying to keep it generic, but in doing so used a name used by the .NET framework.

Comment: Thanks @Tarek. Unfortunately after following this I can't see the Client/Reponse classes that should have been generated. Maybe the WSDL or VS didnt correctly define the classes? (Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000). Have added a image showing what I have.

Comment: Can also confirm the WSDL was generated from `https://wsbexpress.dhl.com/sndpt/expressRateBook?WSDL`

Comment: Ah, I think I see the issue. When you create the service reference, you need to go into advanced and select "Always Generate Message Contracts." I've created an example app which compiles and _should work_. You can download it from https://github.com/tHeCh0s3n0n3/.net-WSSE-example

Comment: Many thanks Tarek! I was adding the wsdl as a web reference rather than a service reference. Very stupid mistake!